# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'break' (T_BREAK) php spider

Tags: php, web-crawler

I'm trying to exclude links in a PHP spider. Here is the block that is returning the error

```
// Exclude links in exclusion array
for($xx=0; $xx<count($exclusion_array); $xx++)
    {
    if(stristr($link, $exclusion_array[$xx]))
        {
        echo "Ignored excluded link : $link\n";
        $exclude=true
        break;
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there perhaps a problem somewhere else that could make this "unexpected break" error show up?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon on this line: `$exclude=true`.

Comment: Typographical error questions are off-topic.

Comment: @Sparky thanks I'll try not to do that again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a terminating semi clone `(;)` after `$exclude=true;`.

```
if(stristr($link, $exclusion_array[$xx])) { 
    echo "Ignored excluded link : $link\n"; 
    $exclude=true;
                ^^^
    break; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$exclude=true // You are missing a semi-colon here.
```

add a semi-colon like this

```
$exclude=true;
```